# Downloading content from Apple hosted in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an in-app purchase which is Apple hosted. However I can't figure out how to download the content associated with it.
I could get the downloadable objects and request the download start:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:currentTransaction.downloads];
```

that's when I get lost: what should I do after that?
I have taken a look at Apple doc and didn't find anything that could possibly help me.

Thx

Comment: Did you got the resolution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem. Calling the

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:currentTransaction.downloads];
```

then

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
```

is constantly called back. I guess I had forgotten some delegates or something like that. Besides that, I deleted the app from my device and re-compiled it again from Xcode. Then it worked like a charm =) Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm until download fails. Then what?

Answer (score 0):

Implement an SKPaymentTransactionObserver. The observer will be notified when the payment queue changes status. For example, paymentQueue:updatedDownloads: will be called with an array of SKDownloads whose downloadState indicates the status change for a download. If you want to know about completed downloads, look for downloadState == SKDownloadStateFinished.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, I did implement the SKPaymentTransactionObserver. Moreover, I put an NSlog at the very beginning just to know if the method was called. I've tried with different test accounts but the (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads is never called. My download is stuck in the limbo

Comment: do you know what kind of content comes when you download? Zip? Pkg? what? If it is a zip package what is inside when you unzip, just the content file or a folder structure?

Comment: The content is a zip, but it's accessible as a folder structure. There's a plist and a folder called Contents which has whatever you put in the download. You can use iExplorer to see what it looks like on the phone.

Comment: Marcelo, you'd need to post more code so we can see what else might be wrong. You might want to compare your code to MKStoreKit.